# Компиляция программ на golang в linux

Tags: linux, golang

Пишу элементарный хелловорд:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main()  {
    fmt.Println("Hello")
}
```

`go run` выполняет его нормально, делаю `go build`, запускаю, выводит ошибки типа:

```
go1: 1: go1: ELF: not found
go1: 2: go1: p�: not found
go1: 3: go1: �: not found
go1: 3: go1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

Как мы видим, если запустить сам исходник, то сообщение и ошибка отличаются
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что то мне кажется, что скомпилированный бинарь по какой то причине получается под другую платформу (или его запускаете неверно). Что показывает команда file? (то есть, в консоле выполнить `file имя_бинарника`

Comment: 1: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, not stripped

Comment: а сам линукс 32 битный или 64?

Comment: в интернете нашел такую команду sudo GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=0 ./make.bash --no-clean, но у меня не находит ./make.bash

Comment: а зачем указывать, что у Вас виндовс? это команда нужна, если вы решили сами собрать кросплатформенно. Но Вам то этого не нужно

Comment: линукс 64 битный

Comment: да нет, это пример, понятно что я указываю там линукс

Comment: м, я кажется все понял. Вы пытаетесь запустить не скомпилированный бинарь, а сам go файл. Но он в кодировке utf16.

Comment: да как раз нет.

Comment: видимо нужно  будет показать скриншот консоли с проблемой

Comment: все почти как я и ожидал - Вы неверно запускаете - нужно вот так `./l` (или там все таки единица?)

Comment: единица. и ./ ничего не меняет

Comment: Нужно без sh  в начале

Comment: Да, так работает

Comment: А зачем Вы скомпилированный go-файл передаёте шеллу? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, что бы в линуксе запустить бинарник, он должен быть в путях поиска (посмотреть их можно через `echo $PATH`). Так как текущий каталог (то есть, точка) по умолчанию не включен в пути (но всяко бывает), то нужно либо явно указать путь, либо добавить текущий каталог в пути (что не правильно).

Итого. лучше запускать так

```
./name
```

(да, точка и слеш в начале. name - имя бинаря).

Запуская через sh/bash мы предполагаем, что там скрипт (что не соответствует действительности) и sh стает немного плохо:). Если все таки хочется запустить через него (ну мало чего), то это делается так

```
sh -c ./name
```